# SQL statement to delete multiple fields in a table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I could finally solve the DELETE CASCADE. for these tables.

[image: http://subefotos.com/ver/?a6f811bfb78e9aa78ffe43adb1f3cf5do.png]

Now... I need delete all row on AlergiaTipo when these seems related to a alergiagrupo on the table ALERGIA. 
I make this statement.

```
delete from alergiatipo where ID in (select alergiatipo.ID from alergia,alergiatipo where
alergia.AlergiaTipo_ID = alergiatipo.iD and alergia.ID in (select alergia.ID from 
alergia,alergiagrupo where alergia.AlergiaGrupo_ID = alergiagrupo.ID AND 
alergiagrupo.ID = '2'));
```

but return me this error

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'alergiatipo' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your `delete` with proper explicit `join` syntax:

```
delete from alergiatipo
    where ID in (select alergiatipo.ID
                 from alergia join
                      alergiatipo
                      on alergia.AlergiaTipo_ID = alergiatipo.iD
                 where alergia.ID in (select alergia.ID 
                                      from alergia join
                                           alergiagrupo 
                                           on alergia.AlergiaGrupo_ID = alergiagrupo.ID 
                                      where alergiagrupo.ID = '2'
                                     )
               );
```

In MySQL, you cannot specify the table being deleted elsewhere in an `update` or `delete`.  Plus, your delete is rather overdone.  I think you just want the following:

```
delete alt
    from alergiatipo alt join
         alergia a
         on a.AlergiaTipo_ID = alt.iD join
         alergiagrupo ag
         on a.AlergiaGrupo_ID = ag.ID
    where ag.ID = 2;
```

I also removed the single quotes around `2`.  I'm guessing the column is an integer, so you should use an integer constant rather than a string constant.